# curving prodecural texture along an object (road Texture)

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

how can i make a procedural texture follow a curved path?
something link this (the yellow lines on the sides)

[image]

Thank you

Comment: why don't you want to use an image texture for the lines?

Comment: Perhaps I am a bit late. Have you tried using UV coords as your texture coords? From what I've tested with a simple plane + wave texture, it seems to do the trick